# Vue js custom component options

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Some libraries (Like Vuelidate for example)
take adventage of Vue's Option Structure and create their own $option.

For example Vuelidate has a 'validations' option
so you component may look like this

```
data(){return{}}, 
created(){},
mounted(){},
computed(){},
validations(){},
```

even a library like vue-rx has a `subscriptions(){}` option in the component structure
I've created this huge table framework for my company's project.
the whole front-end uses it and I'd love the ability to create a custom option just for the table
like

```
table(){}
```

for my teammates to be able to use.

I couldn't find any documentation on how to create that.

Any ideas?

Comment: Vuelidate, for example, just seems to be a fancy [Vue mixin](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html). You can see how it gets wired up in its [source code](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/blob/master/src/index.js#L572).